# NHibernate caching entities across sessions using SysCache

Tags: nhibernate, second-level-cache

I'm developing a web application and I would like caching to persist across web requests. 
I am aware that the first level cache is per-session only. I have second-level caching enabled and this is working for queries.

However, the second-level cache does not seem to work for "getting" entities... therefore most of the DB work the application does is not being cached across web requests.

Is this normal / desirable behaviour? I'm reviewing one particular page that makes lots of round trips to the database, although each query is quick, these seem unnecessary if the entities could be cached.

*Edit*

Okay so I have second level cache enabled, and working for queries. I just can't seem to get it working for entities. I have `Cache.Is(c => c.ReadWrite())` (fluent nhibernate) on my main entity that I'm testing. But nope, it still hits the DB each time. Any ideas?

*Edit*

I've tried using transactions like so:

```
public override Accommodation Get(int id) 
{ 
    using (var tx = Session.BeginTransaction()) 
    { 
        var accomm = Session.Get<Accommodation>(id); 
        tx.Commit(); 
        return accomm; 
    } 
}
```

My mapping is such (and you can see we have a nasty schema):

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<Core.Entities.Itinerary.Accommodation.Accommodation> mapping)
{
    mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.Features).Table("AccommodationLinkFeatureType").ChildKeyColumn("FeatureTypeId").NotFound.Ignore();
    mapping.HasManyToMany(x => x.SimilarAccommodation).Table("AccommodationLinkSimilarAccommodation").ChildKeyColumn("SimilarAccommodationId").NotFound.Ignore();
    mapping.HasMany(x => x.TourItinerary).Table("AccommodationTourItinerary");
    mapping.HasOne(x => x.Images).ForeignKey("AccommodationId").Cascade.All().Not.LazyLoad();
    mapping.References(x => x.CollectionType).NotFound.Ignore().Not.LazyLoad();
    mapping.References(x => x.AccommodationUnitType).NotFound.Ignore().Not.LazyLoad();
    Cache.Is(c => c.ReadWrite());
}
```

However, this still doesn't seem to fetch from the 2nd level cache.

Incidentally, I see a lot of examples online using `Cache.ReadWrite()` but I can only see an `Is` method on the Cache helper, so I'm trying `Cache.Is(c => c.ReadWrite())` -- has the fluent interface changed?

Comment: The easiest way would be saving your NHibernate session inside of a web session, but I am NOT recommending this :P You should probably fix your 2nd level caching - have you read this post: http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate.aspx ?

Comment: +1 for the link, but see my edit

Comment: which provider are you using? if using memcached check manually if the entities are actually present there before making the get.

Answer (score 4):

I have not tested this, but my understanding is that committing transactions is the magic that places objects into second level cache. If you are doing read operations outside of a transaction then the objects will not be placed in the second level cache.

Comment: Thanks, I'd just discovered this too. See http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
In my case the cause was the References is mapped with NotFound().Ignore() (i.e if no entity is found with this foreign key just ignore it, which is actualy a data consistency error anyway). Remove NotFound.Ignore and fix your db.

Comment: All when and good, unless your working with a legacy database over which you don't have complete control of data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you´re having some problem with the configuration of your cache provider. I´ve been able to do want you want using Couchbase as 2nd level cache provider, as described here:

http://blog.couchbase.com/introducing-nhibernate-couchbase-2nd-level-cache-provider

If your deployment enviroment is on Azure, i guess this might be useful. Note that The SysCache module can’t co-exist with the AzureMemcached module.

http://www.webmoco.com/webmoco-development-blog/orchard-cms-second-level-caching